# Another Hadith on Shaking Hands

Tags: hadith-interpretation, authenticity

What is the authenticity of the following hadith:

> "Any of the female slaves of Medina could take hold of the hand of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and take him wherever she wished." (Sahih al-Bukhari 6072).

How have our scholars interpreted this hadith?

Comment: What is unclear about this hadith? The rulings for slaves and free people have been different so there's no necessity for interpretation.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Not all scholars make this distinction.

Comment: I don't know of any who don't. Can you tell me some? And what is their evidence especially for cases which are mentioned in the qur'an?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Such as Yusuf Qaradawi. He didn't make this distinction in his writing.

Comment: Either you misunderstood him or he shows again his ignorance.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Well, when presenting this hadith, I don't believe he made a distinction. However, it is possible that I misinterpreted. Do you know of the authenticity by any chance?

Comment: It is in sahih al-Bukhari so it's authenticity is beyond any doubt. Note that no reliable scholar today would accept the existence of legal slavery today maybe al-Qaradawi is speaking about the actual case. In that case this hadith can be considered as nothing more than a historical relict as the ruling is basically abrogated due to modern laws and regulations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101141/discussion-between-haseeb-faisal-and-medi1saif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is from the *Sahih* of Bukhari, so it meets his criterion of authenticity.

The hadith is an expression to convey the generosity and humility of the Prophet ﷺ, that he would attend to the needs of anyone: not just men but also women, not just free people but also slaves, not just a prominent slave but any common slave, and that he would go out of his way to be helpful.

Similarly, **لتأخذ بيد رسول الله** (could take hold of the hand of the Messenger of Allah) is used as a figure of speech for the Prophet's behavior being kind and humble to an extreme and for being available for help, it does not mean that his hand was literally touched by a stranger woman.

> والمقصود من الأخذ باليد لازمه وهو الرفق والانقياد وقد اشتمل على أنواع من المبالغة في التواضع لذكره المرأة دون الرجل والأمة دون الحرة وحيث عمم بلفظ الإماء أي أمة كانت وبقوله حيث شاءت أي من الأمكنة والتعبير بالأخذ باليد إشارة إلى غاية التصرف حتى لو كانت حاجتها خارج المدينة والتمست منه مساعدتها في تلك الحاجة لساعد على ذلك وهذا دال على مزيد تواضعه وبراءته من جميع أنواع الكبر صلى الله عليه وسلم
>
> <sup>— [Fath al-Bari](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/6251)</sup>

Even if we are to interpret it literally, the text is about slaves and can not be extended to free women. In various madhabs the ruling on a slave is that of a Mahram in matters of 'Awrah.

Comment: But weren't slaves only permissible for those that possessed them? Sorry if this is an ignorant question.

Comment: @HaseebFaisal Intimate relations are only permitted for those who possess them or are married to them, however a stranger may see them when it is without desire or fear of sin. Evidence for the permission includes the [hadith of  Saffiyah](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/23) etc. Also It becomes necessary to do so in various situations, e.g. if the slave is being bought, or when the slave has to do some task.

Comment: I have a last question, if you don't mind. Are the hadiths on women shaking hands with gloves authentic? I've never seen them cited. Of course, you don't need to cite these hadiths.